# Electrolysis of gasoline (or other uniform liquid hydrocarbon)

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis, hydrocarbons

Electrolysis, when I usually search about it, is almost exclusively interested in splitting $\ce{H2O}$. However, looking at the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis) on electrolysis, it seems like it works for a bunch of other molecules. Could one perform electrolysis on gasoline, or some other hydrocarbon? In other words, can one [dehydrogenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehydrogenation) hydrocarbons using electricity?

Maybe gasoline is too non-uniform. It seems like this would generate a lot of hydrogen.

Comment: Interesting question, but how are you going to perform the electrolysis of a non-conductive liquid? Theoretically, you can add supporting electrolytes, but this needs to be specified in the question.

Comment: Organic electrochemistry is a thing and is a subject of considerable interest these days. A substantial part of my PhD was in synthetic electrochemistry back in the 80s.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question? The production of hydrogen?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, partially the production of hydrogen, since H2O electrolysis is mainly used for that, and it seems like they're always looking for improvements.  Figured something like methane, or other high H ratio hydrocarbons, would produce better (if it worked).  Partially, also just curiosity as to whether electrolysis would work with something like gasoline or a hydrocarbon.  Per andselisk's note above, apparently would need some way to gain enough conductivity.  (maybe just a close enough charge gap?)

Comment: @Waylander, have not read about organic electrochemistry previously, although that's pretty neat from a [quick summary like this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2451929420304356).  Looks like selective catalysis of chemistry based on electrical input to encourage / discourage certain reactions.  Seems like there could be lots of potential with different AC/DC, voltages, currents, waveforms, frequencies, electrode shapes, ect...

Comment: @G.Putnam Please append such motivation to the question itself. Comments are ephemeral